# Freestyle Lines Breaking with Animated Vertex Groups...Fixable?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, freestyle

Hey there Blender Community,

I am attempting to use Freestyle in Cycles to add an outline to an animated object that varies in transparency and shape (keyframed shape keys).

I'm having an issue whereby the outline of the object seems to break at various stages of the animation (see the images below).

Is there a way to fix this?

Functioning Freestyle Outline:
[image: Functioning Freestyle Outline]

Dysfunctional Freestyle Outlines:
[image: Dysfunctional Freestyle Outline]

[image]

My Current Freestyle Configuration:

[image]

Comment: you mean "keyframed shape keys"? Maybe use **Сontour** instead of **Border**?

Comment: Keyframed shape keys is indeed what I meant. I've edited the question accordingly. Unfortunately, using Contour instead of Border produces this a weird effect with lines going every which away across the face of the object...

Comment: What happens if you disable the Face Smoothness option?